# PHP error with file get contents

Tags: php

Can someone help me identify the error here:

```
<?php
$city=$_GET['city'];
$city=str_replace(" ", "", $city);
$contents=@file_get_contents("http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/'.$city'/forecasts/latest");
preg_match('/<span class="phrase">(.*?)</s', $contents, $matches);
echo @$matches[1];
?>
```

for some reason the code is giving me error, however, if i removed the city and replace it with a specific city (london, paris, cairo) the code work, but when I put it City.. the code is not working .

can someone help me identify the error or how to make work.

Comment: change this `"http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/'.$city'/forecasts/latest"` to `"http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/$city/forecasts/latest"`. then try

Comment: Reformat your question (bold is not needed). What is the value of $city just before executing the $contents line?

Comment: There is an error in string concatenation.

Comment: i tried and did not work @D Desai

Comment: can u elaborate more on the error - Afshan ?

Comment: Provide the error. `$city` should be urlencoded, I'd guess replacing the spaces would cause issues with spaced cities, e.g. `las vegas`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First of all remove `@` from all your code line(don't escape from error, try to find and resolve them).*

***Second change `$contents` line like below:-***

```
$contents= file_get_contents("http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/$city/forecasts/latest");
```

Or

```
$contents= file_get_contents("http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/'".$city."'/forecasts/latest");
```

Note:- string concatenation problem is there in your code

Comment: Thank you .. it works now... i used your $city and worked.

Comment: @Farida  glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$city=$_GET['city'];
$city=str_replace(" ", "", $city);
$contents=file_get_contents('http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/'.$city.'/forecasts/latest');
preg_match('/<span class="phrase">(.*?)</s', $contents, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
?>
```

Comment: Please do not merely post code but also explain the pivotal change.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check parsing of $city variable like this

```
$contents = @file_get_contents("http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/".$city."/forecasts/latest");
```